# Give credit to an answer in a scientific publication

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

### The problem

I am a scientist and I have been working in statistical analysis for a while, and I have been wondering if there would be a way of crediting the author of an answer that was essential on the analyses of a scientific research either citing the answer within the references, or some other option.

### Proposed solution

I think it would be a good idea, to be able to export a question as a bibtex citation or some other similar option in order to give credit not only as points but also through the literature. The author would be Either the user name, or if you add it to your profile, it could be a citation name.

Do you think this would be possible, and is there any other proposed solutions?

Comment: Relevant question at Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49760

Comment: Some sites already have this feature, e.g. math or physics https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1z13.png

Comment: Do you want to cite a source, or credit an author? Citing any of my [so] data would not credit me as a scientist, for example. I don't publish under my [so] handle…

Comment: That is super interesting @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, why some and not all? Is each site independent?

Comment: What style guide does your paper follow? It should already cover how to cite an internet source I would think.

Comment: @DerekCorcoran Some sites have it because those sites are so heavily used for citations and it's such a big part of that site's field. It would make little sense to have a "cite" feature for a gardening site or a puzzling site. Though to be honest, Stack Overflow should have a cite feature for sure, because legally code taken from here *has* to be cited/attributed. We all know that's probably done less than 5% of the time though

Comment: @TylerH My understanding is that the citation tool is designed more for bibliographies rather than code comments but the tool itself hasn't been touched for years and isn't even well documented. I think that, if we were going to implement it for SO, it'd need a pretty major overhaul so that it was easier to use.

Comment: @Catija I certainly agree with that, too :-) It'd probably be faster to just start with the April 1st "copy & paste" detector or something!

Comment: You think that was only a April Fools day gag? You poor, poor naïve child. They are watching. Everything you do. Watching and recording. And then, when you least expect it (and maybe when you do expect it because by then it will be too late to stop them) they will strike.